# Illegal Syntax for Set Operation with selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

i have two input texts to hide/show password as follows:

```
<ice:panelGroup rendered="#{conf.password}">
  <ice:inputText id="valPassDisabled" value="#########" style="width:70%" rendered="#{!conf.showPassword}"  />
  <ice:inputText id="valPassEnabled" value="#{conf.confvalue}" style="width:70%" rendered="#{conf.showPassword}"  />
  <h:outputText value="Show Password"/>
  <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{conf.showPassword}" partialSubmit="true"/>
</ice:panelGroup>
```

when i click on the selectBooleanCheckbox i am getting the exception:

**Illegal Syntax for Set Operation**

please advise why i am getting this exception and how to solve it.

Comment: try to replace `value="#########"` with `value="someText"` or try to add `escape="false"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error was because i am using an **illegal value #########** when i changed it, the exception was gone.